# Is it possible to spell out numbers in words with a separator?

Tags: objective-c

I'm aware of NSNumberFormatter's NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle, but that returns poorly formatted numbers: 932 returns "nine hundred thirty-two" rather than "nine-hundred and thirty-two".

In a  [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6553337/1205506) Dave DeLong said that he got "nine hundred and thirty-two" for the same code, which is exactly what I want - the word "and" (or whatever that may be when localized) used to separate large numbers. Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for?  Just an "and" added for the part under 100?  Have you tried various larger numbers to see if there are other situations where the default behavior doesn't give you what you want?

Comment: I believe adding the `and` would be grammatically incorrect or poor English at the very least.

Comment: While I disagree with the op's use of "poorly formatted" to describe the formatter's output, I don't think putting the "and" in is incorrect (American) english -- I've certainly heard it used both ways quite a bit (I don't know what the "formal rule" is, if there is such a thing, but colloquial use certainly would include both ways as common).

Comment: Actually, in American English, "and" should only be used to separate the dollars and cents, but in British English, "and" is used as described:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#Numbers   I have no idea what dialect the OP is targeting though....

Comment: That being said, I tried changing the locale of the number formatter to en_GB and it still didn't add the and (which I believe that it **should** since it is proper British English).

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications! I did try a variety of EN_ locales to see if I could get some variety. To give an example that I feel works regardless of dialect, "101 Dalmatians" seems to universally want an "and" :)

Comment: @Inafziger is correct, I'm assured by my daughter who is much better educated in these things than, I, a scientist who never liked english class. Even with 101, you should write "one hundred one", though that's one that most people would say, incorrectly, with an "and".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the "and" added, I think you'll have to do it manually (either the behavior has changed since the question you referenced was answered, or that was a typo in the answer).
I think you could do it this way, but I don't know if this will work in all situations that you want it to:

```
    int num = 932;
    int leftNum = floor(num/100) * 100;
    int rightNum = num % 100;
    NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
    NSString *combo;
    if (num > 100) {
        NSString *l = [f stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:leftNum]];
        NSString *r = [f stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rightNum]];
        combo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ and %@",l,r];
    }else{
        combo = [f stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:num]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", combo);
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely fixes the precisely problem represented with 932, but I believe "and" is to be inserted in a variety of other places - "one million three hundred and thirty-eight thousand and one", for example.

Comment: You'll have to think of all those places you want an a"and" and write your own rules using my post as a guideline.