# NSNumberFormatter: spelling out a number with AND particle (British spelling)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter, avspeechsynthesizer

The following code:

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer * speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString: @"112"];
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-GB"];
speechSynthesizer  speakUtterance:utterance];
```

results in with the device saying: "one hundred **and** twelve" (British spelling)

But if instead you transliterate the number 112:

```
NSString * wordNumber = nil;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-GB"]];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
wordNumber = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(112)];
```

now wordNumber contains "one hundred twelve" (without the and particle).

So:

```
@"112" -> AVSpeechSynthesizer -> "one hundred and twelve"
@"112" -> NSNumberFormatter   -> "one hundred twelve"
```

How can I transliterate  a number with the **and** particles,i.e, British spelling?

Comment: Argument to `stringFromNumber` should be `@112` instead of string literal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to spell out numbers in words with a separator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250126/is-it-possible-to-spell-out-numbers-in-words-with-a-separator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll need to do this yourself. I haven't been able to produce your desired result or find any resource that allows me to do so.

I've linked to a question that demonstrates how to do this manually.

[Is it possible to spell out numbers in words with a separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250126/is-it-possible-to-spell-out-numbers-in-words-with-a-separator)

Answer (score 0):

Huh, can't you just do this?

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"112"];
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-GB"];
NSString *transliteration = utterance.speechString;
```